# Algorithm to count maximum possible pairs

Tags: algorithm

I have an array of numbers say `arr=[3,4,2,3,1]`. Here index of `arr` represents number while `arr[index]` represents the frequency of that number. For the example `arr` we have

```
1 three times
2 four times
3 two times
4 three times
5 one time
```

A pair can consist of two numbers such that their absolute difference is either 0 or 1.
We need to find maximum possible pairs. A number cannot be used more than its provided frequency. For the example `arr` pairs can be:
`(1,1),(2,2),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(4,5)`
Thus **6** is the answer.
Note: Here we are left with an extra 1 but that doesn't matter.

**My approach:**
Calculate the mod 2 for each number and obtain an array of 0 and 1 and for each frequency update count by `count += arr[i]/2`.
So for the example `arr` I will be left with:
`[1,0,0,1,1]`
Now if I see any two consecutive 1 update count by 1

It worked for sample test cases but failed in hidden test cases. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my idea?

**Failed Case:**
[34,2,435,45,57,6,8,3,57,235]
My output: 440
Expected output: 441

Comment: The simplest example where your approach goes wrong: `[1, 2, 1]`. If you greedily pick the pair `(2, 2)` you end up with `[1, 0, 1]` and there are no more matches possible. But the optimal pairing is of course `(1, 2), (2, 3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logic behind is

> take arr[i]/2 into the count and if odd is element take one as a carry
> for the next

```
      public static void main(String args[]) {
                int[] arr=new int[]{34,2,435,45,57,6,8,3,57,235};
                int len=arr.length;
                int count=0,prev=0;
                if(arr[0]%2!=0)prev=1;
                count+=arr[0]/2;
                for(int i=1;i<len;i++){
                    if(prev==1){
                       arr[i]--;
                       count++;
                    }
                    if(arr[i]%2!=0)prev=1;
                    else prev=0;
                    count+=arr[i]/2;
                    
                }
        
              System.out.println(count);
        }
```

> Time Complexity is O(n) and space is O(1)

Answer (score 1):

Note that with your approach you don't use the last one from 57.

But you can pair this one with one from 6, another one from 6 will be paired with 8, 8 will paired with 3, and 57 with 235 - so all items do work.

You need to choose at every step: what's better - left last one free or make a pair with the next value.